# How to read time in url and how to write on url?

Tags: php, mysql

I created QR code according to url like this

```
www.sitename.com/index.php?user_idx=1
```

And read this url another function. (Because nodemcu send this link to my website when I came with this url, user1's value change)

But I want to write id and time:

For example

```
www.sitename.com/index.php?user_idx=1?hh:mm:ss
```

And I want to refresh every 30 seconds.
How can I write this on url

When I read every 30 second this url has to be match.

How can I do this ?

**EDIT 1**

I try this but it didnt work.

Read function:

```
<?php
if(!(  empty($_GET['user_idx']) && empty($_GET['sec']) )){
      $t = time(); // get sec since 1970-01-01
      $t = $t - ($t % 30); // get the closest time divided by 30 sec
      if($_GET['sec'] != $t){
            $user_idx=$_GET['user_idx'];
   require_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET balance=balance-5 WHERE user_idx='$user_idx';";
   mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   $results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user_nick FROM users WHERE user_idx= '$user_idx'");
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
$usname= $row['user_nick'];
}
$sql3="INSERT INTO openmv (usr_name,pass_time,usr_idx) values ('$usname',NOW(),'$user_idx')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);

}

      }


?>
```

Wrte function:

```
}   else if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
              if(($balance>=5)){
                  $t = time(); // get sec since 1970-01-01
                  $t = $t - ($t % 30); // get the closest time divided by 30 sec
                  if(($_GET['sec'] != $t))
                   $text="http://sitename.com/project/index.php?user_idx={$_SESSION["userID"]}&sec=$t";
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
 Başarılı bir şekilde giriş yaptınız.
</div>';
               QRcode::png($text,$file,'L',10,2);
            echo "<center><img src='".$file."'></center> " ;  
              }
              else if($balance < 5){
                  echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
Kartınızda bakiye yok lütfen yükleme yapınız !</div>
<a href="balance_info.php"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Para yükle</button></a>

';
              }



}
```

**FAILS**

And for example time 1560323000
When I go to
sitename.com/project/index.php?luser_idx=1&sec=1560323000
 anything change please help me

Comment: You may need to explain more about how it didn't work. Is there are any exception?
Also it will be nice if you can format your code before paste it. And please try to paste a executable code.

Comment: for example time 1560323000 when I go to this addres 

http://sitename.com/project/index.php?luser_idx=1&sec=1560323000 , balance value not change

Comment: Have see my comment? `$t = $t - ($t % 30); // get the closest time divided by 30 sec`
You change 30 sec to 1000 sec, It means it the balance value will change after 16 min. try to change it to 10 sec and see if the balance value change after 10 sec.

Comment: I tried that type and didnt work so I change this 1000 and it didnt work again

Comment: `if(!$_GET['sec'] == $t)`  remove the `!` in read function and replace `==` with `!=` .

Comment: Now, I cant see QR code in the write blocks

Comment: if(($_GET['sec'] =! $t)) not working truely

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` to combine multi param in url `?user_idx=1&sec=1560321720`. Search `query string` for more detail.

For generate the url

```
$t = time(); // get sec since 1970-01-01
$t = $t - ($t % 30); // get the closest time divided by 30 sec
$url = 'www.sitename.com/index.php?user_idx=1&sec='.$t;  
echo($url);
```

For read the url

```
$t = time(); // get sec since 1970-01-01
$t = $t - ($t % 30); // get the closest time divided by 30 sec
if($_GET['sec'] == $t){
    return false; // if they are same, return false and change nothing.
}else{
    return $new_data; // return new data.
}
```

Comment: It didnt work. I update my question with code please check

Comment: for example time 1560323000 When I go to sitename.com/project/index.php?luser_idx=1&sec=1560323000 anything change please help me

Comment: `if(($_GET['sec'] =! $t))` Change `=!` to `!=`. learn more about operator from here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Comment: I change in also read and write function. But when I go to this url anythng change so in the read side if($_GET['sec'] != $t) { ...} blocks not working